# How enable mbstring in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, mbstring

If anybody know how to enable mbstring in codeigniter

```
then please tell how to enable mbstring in codeigniter
```

Comment: This article might help you http://kuroir.tumblr.com/post/736312384/codeigniter-2-0-and-multibyte-support

Comment: There is two possible solutions in this article.. Try both and see if they are any good

Comment: i searched it,but not found

Answer (score 0):

i enabled mbstring from cpanel.the problem solved :)